# Mark cells on excel VBA if they are merged when double clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I am puuting a check mark on double click on certain cells. My code looks like this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AA38:AK48,M32:M40,M42:M52,M54:M69")) Is Nothing Then
  Cancel = True
  If VarType(Target.Value) = vbBoolean Then
    Target.Value = Not (Target.Value)
  Else
    Target.Value = IIf(Target.Value = "ü", Null, "ü")
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

But on the Merged cellls AA-AK it gives me an error

Comment: Short answer is don't use merged cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AA38:AK48,M32:M40,M42:M52,M54:M69")) Is Nothing Then
  Cancel = True
  If VarType(Target.Cells(1).Value) = vbBoolean Then
    Target.Cells(1).Value = Not (Target.Cells(1).Value)
  Else
    Target.Cells(1).Value = IIf(Target.Cells(1).Value = "ü", Null, "ü")
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or simply add `Set Target = Target.Cells(1)` at the beginning ;)

Comment: Yes, that would also do the trick and will need less typing as well. :)